# Targeting large files

Tags: files, search

Often I am surprised by my disk getting stuffed, and wonder if
there's a nice utility to report all files/dirs that occupy more
than a given amount of space. I hope duplicates are removed as
well, so for example (say the par is 50GB)

```
60GB .. ~/Dropbox
59GB .. ~/Dropbox/bigfile
```

Then only the later should be shown. This way, I can immediately
target where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

specifically the -size option

something like:

```
find <path_to_directory> -type f -size +50M
```

This would only target files (`-type f`) that are larger than 50 MB (`-size +50M`) in the directory of your choice (`<path_to_directory>`)